# How to play video forward and backward?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

I am analyzing some videos and I would be very comfortable with a function to see the video forward and backward on occasion. I thought it was an achievable result with negative speed, but at least in VLC isn't it?  Is there any program that allows it?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to render out a new video playing backwards. The problem here is there are many different codecs and ways to save video to play on a device. Most do not save video each frame individually in order. One, IIRC mpeg-2, only saves differences between frames.